# Recursive Summation Method

Tags: java, recursion, methods

I am currently working on a recursive summation method in java, this is my code so far however I am running into some issues during runtime with ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. This is the completed code to this point.

```
   import java.util.Scanner;
   public class Summation {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    input();
   }

    private static void input() {
       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Lower bound: ");
        int lower = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Upper bound: ");
        int upper = scanner.nextInt();
        arrayForm(upper, lower);
   }

   private static void arrayForm(int upper, int lower) {
        int b = 0;
        int a = Math.abs(lower) + Math.abs(upper);
        int array[] = new int[a];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
           array[i] = lower + i;
        }
       summation(array, b);
   }

   public static int summation(int array[], int b) {
       if (b > array.length) {
        System.out.println("Cannot continue");
        return 0;
    } else{
        int result = array[b] + summation(array, b + 1);
        System.out.println("recursion call: " + b);
        System.out.println("sum: " + result);
        System.out.println("parameter 1: " + array[b]);
        System.out.println("parameter 2: " + array[b + 1]);
        return result;
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Arrays go from `0` to `length-1`, you're stopping at `> length` where you should be stopping at `== length` - this is a off-by-one mistake.

Comment: Since you're calling `summation(array, b + 1)`, it actually needs to be `(b > array.length - 2)` or `(b >= array.length - 1)`

Comment: Do you mean this line "if (b > array.length)" should be "if (b == array.length)"? Because I still get the same errors?                                >

Comment: Add `System.out.println("array.length=" + array.length + ", b=" + b);` as the first line in `summation` and see what it tells you.

Comment: What do you really want to do? sum from lower to upper?

Comment: Yeah I have to get the sum from a lower bound to an upper bound

Comment: I don't think you even _need_ an array... can't you just sum the integers in the loop?

Comment: I just started coding recently and I'm only 17 years old, I have been trying to figure it out for a while now could someone please fix the code for me so I can compile it and understand how it works. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in your code:

1. fix b >= array.length: If i give the bounds 1 to 10 The array has 11 elements. That leads to an index of 0 to 10. If you call array[b] with b = array.length, length is 11 and that's out of bounds.
2. array.length - 1: Becouse you are calling summation(array, b + 1) the index b must not exceed max-index - 1. E.g. bounds: 1 to 10. So summation(array, 10) calls summation(array, 11) and thats the last element in the array.

so the summation(a,b) function looks like this:

```
    public static int summation(int array[], int b) {
    if (b >= array.length - 1) {
        System.out.println("Cannot continue");
        return 0;
    } else {
        int result = array[b] + summation(array, b + 1);
        System.out.println("recursion call: " + b);
        System.out.println("sum: " + result);
        System.out.println("parameter 1: " + array[b]);
        System.out.println("parameter 2: " + array[b + 1]);
        System.out.println();
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Lower bound: 2
Upper bound: 4
Cannot continue
recursion call: 4
sum: 6
parameter 1: 6
parameter 2: 7

recursion call: 3
sum: 11
parameter 1: 5
parameter 2: 6

recursion call: 2
sum: 15
parameter 1: 4
parameter 2: 5

recursion call: 1
sum: 18
parameter 1: 3
parameter 2: 4

recursion call: 0
sum: 20
parameter 1: 2
parameter 2: 3


Process completed.

Comment: This is the output I got thanks for the help I believe it is right!

Answer (score 0):

In the else-part:

```
   System.out.println("parameter 2: " + array[b + 1]);
```

requires for a valid index:

```
b + 1 < array.length
b < array.length - 1
```

But the if-else merely guarantees:

```
b <= array.length
b < array.length + 1
```

Hence it should be

```
if (b >= array.length - 1) { ... } else { ... }
```

Amd then there is probably an error in the logic if you intended:

```
sum of lower + (lower + 1) + (lower + 2) + ... + upper
```

These are (upper - lower + 1) terms of average (upper + lower)/2:

```
int sum = (upper - lower + 1) * (upper + lower) / 2;
```

Either one of the factors is even as they differ by `2*lower+1`, so integer calculation is okay: integer division by does not loose anything.

Example

```
sum(7, 9) = (9 - 7 + 1) * (9 + 7) = 3 * 16 = 48
```

Comment: I got the code up and running now thanks for the help!